# Android SDK could not be found

Tags: xamarin.android

some where on Xamarin forum i found that i did not had android>>BuildTool>>19.0,19.3 and all that. so i open up and installed all these pakages. But now i open visual studio and open project (Android App) this exception is comming on Main.axml

Exception:
The Android SDK could not be found. Make sure the path to the SDK is correctly configured in the Xamarin studio option and that you have installed the plateform tools and atleast one plateform SDK.

Please help me getting out of this exception .
 Thanks!

Comment: Did you receive some kind of exception?

Comment: just im seeing Android SDK could not be found.. but it is installed in my PC i just update it with latest pakages .

Comment: have you configured SDK and NDK path in Visual/Xamarin Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the Android NDK. After the installation, if still doesn't work, try to double check the parts Java JDK (32 bit), Android SDK For more information check over [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change SDK path in Visual Studio Tools->Xamarin to:

"...Android SDK in a AppData folder that's hidden from the user"

[Xamarin Forum which helped me](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/16982/the-android-sdk-could-not-be-found-make-sure-the-path-to-the-sdk-is-correctly-configured-in-the-xam)